# Скрытие и отображение блоков

Tags: angular2

Как с помощью angular 4 скрыть картинку при клике на нее и отобразить input на ее месте. Понимаю, что надо использовать ngShow, ngHide или ngIf [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Уточните, какой версией Angular вы пользуетесь? Потому что вы кинули ссылку на документацию AngularJs, тег вы так же используете AngularJs, но говорите за Angular 4. Имейте ввиду, это принципиально разные фреймворки

Comment: https://angular.io/ последняя, angular 2/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для скрытия элементов вы можете использовать:

```
[hidden]="!variable"
```

либо

```
*ngIf="variable"
```

Разница в том, что `[hidden]` скрывает элемент при помощи CSS стиля display, а `*ngIf` убирает элемент из DOM дерева

Comment: `код`<img src="images/girl.png" 
  width="189" height="255" alt="lorem">
 <input type="text" size="40">`код` а как правильно в таком примере использовать? Кликнули на картинку - скрыли картинку и отобразили инпут?

Comment: Да, именно так, по клику просто изменяете значение variable. Для инпута допустим отображать, если variable false, для картинки true. И просто по клику можно делать что-то типа variable = !variable